# Event emails - auto accepted by google calendar

Tags: email, google-calendar-api

I'm wondering how airline companies, evites and big events manage to create emails that are formatted specifically for the event as seen below:

[image]

and also adds this event automatically to google calendar.

Can anyone direct me to any tutorial or explanation on the methods used?
I searched endlessly and found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is a result of adding a bit of markup to your emails: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/getting-started

An example event:

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> [ {
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "EventReservation",
  "reservationnumber": "9454as",
  "reservationfor": {
    "image": "whatever image url",
    "name": "My event",
    "@type": "Event",
    "enddate": "2016-01-06T20:00:00+00:00",
    "startdate": "2016-01-06T17:00:00+00:00",
    "location": {
      "name": "11th Street",
      "@type": "Place"
    } } } ] </script>
```

Before that make sure to do the registration steps described here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google